# How to do a topological sort from a subset of items from a given graph?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, topological-sort

I have the following problem: You are given a todo list, some items of which depend on others. Write a function that takes a subset of those todos and returns an ordered list of all the todos to complete. The given subset contains one or more of these todos.

I have written a topological sort using Kahn's Algorithm, turning the list I'm given into an adjacency list. When I have the ordered list of todos, I start adding them into another array and stop when it contains all of the items in the given subset.

This works, but I feel like it's a little bit clumsy and inefficient since I am doing a sort on the entire list and then returning a truncated version.

Any thoughts on how to make this solution a little more elegant?

Comment: please tag the language in the question so we can tell what's going on a little easier (it looks like js)

Comment: It is. I'll tag it appropriately, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think of this as a topological sort.  Think of this as "do dependencies first, do not do them twice."  Which is simple recursive function as long as we keep track of what we will do, and what has been done.

The following Python solution may make this clearer.

```
def arrange_tasks(dependencies, todo, in_order=None, done=None):
    if in_order is None:
        in_order = []
    if done is None:
        done = set()

    for item in todo:
        # Do we need to?
        if item not in done:
            # Marking it done first avoids deep recursion on dependency loops!
            done.add(item)
            # Make sure that dependencies happened.
            arrange_tasks(dependencies, dependencies[item], in_order, done)
            # And now this can happen.
            in_order.append(item)
    return in_order

print(arrange_tasks(
    {
        'make a sandwich': ['buy groceries'],
        'buy groceries': ['go to store'],
        'go to store': []
    },
    ['buy groceries']
))
```

Comment: Thank you @btilly, that solved my issue! I also raised an exception if the item is in done, which should catch any cyclical dependencies.

Comment: @Rasha Be careful.  There can be multiple ways to get to a dependency, and that is not an error.  What is an error is getting to a dependency while trying to satisfy that same dependency.  Handling that is a little more subtle.

Comment: Yeah, I also realized that raising an exception if the item is in the done set also triggers if the given subset has more than one task, i.e. 
`arrange_tasks(
    {
        'make a sandwich': ['buy groceries'],
        'buy groceries': ['go to store'],
        'go to store': []
    },
    ['buy groceries', 'make a sandwich']
)`

Now I'm trying to figure out the best way to find and stop cyclical dependencies.

Comment: @Rasha Change `done` to a hash/dictionary/whatever you want to call it that keeps track of the status of the task.  If the task is not in `done`, insert it with a value of -1.  Once the dependencies are satisfied, update the value to 1.  If you encounter the task while its value is -1, throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking a separate filtering pass, you should be able to check each task for addition to the output `filteredTasks` as it is processed for addition to `orderedTasks`.

Since the only other use of `orderedTasks` is to check its length, you should then be able to replace it with a counter.

This might not make your function much faster, but it will simplify your code.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean please? Test each task for what?

Comment: I have changed the wording of my answer; please let me know if it is still unclear.